# Converting content in a textfile from base64string

Tags: c#, encryption

i am practicing encryption and decryption.

After i have decrypted some data, i convert the bytes to base64string and store it in a textfile.

After some time i want to decrypt it again, but for that to work i have to convert the content from base64string to bytes again.

I tried with this:

```
string path = @"C:\encrypt.txt";
string myfile = File.ReadAllText(path);

byte[]  convertion = Convert.FromBase64String(myfile);
```

That will give me an error because the text is actually not a `base64string`.

Is there anyway to do an convertion?

Comment: `because the text is actually not a base64string` If the error says so, then it is not base64string. What can we do?

Comment: sounds like you have solved your problem....

Comment: You aren't saving the text properly, or something is altering the text in the meantime.

Comment: You seem to be unclear as to whether it *is* base64 (as per the start of your post) or whether it's *not* base64 (as per the end of your post).

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following functions for saveing and read base64 strings

```cs
    public static void WriteAllBase64Text(string path, string text)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
    }

    public static string ReadAllBase64Text(string path)
    {
        var bytes=File.ReadAllText(path);
        var encoded = System.Convert.FromBase64String(bytes);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
    }
```

Comment: What us the purpose of converting string `text` to base64 string

Comment: as far as I understood from the question that @user3185801 already saved the value in text file using base64 however he is facing issue with reading